# Any better way to execute something like this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to list all the user's products with a probable association where a flag 'notification' is set to zero.

```
user.probable_associations.where(:notified => 0).collect{|a| Product.where(:id => a.product_id).collect{|p| p.name}}.to_sentence
```

It seems like using a where and collect method twice within the statement isn't very good. Is there a better way to go about this?

Also, the result is something like

```
"[\"Product A\"] and [\"Product B\"]"
```

which is pretty ugly...and I still need to remove the extra punctuation "[\" \"] 
instead of something clean like

```
"Product A and Product B"
```

EDIT based on Rich's Answer, still have issues because notified is a field in associations NOT product:

```
  has_many :probable_associations, -> { where "associations.category = 3"}, class_name: 'Association', before_add: :set_probable_category
  has_many :probable_products, class_name: 'Product', through: :probable_associations, source: :product do
    def not_notified
        select(:name).where(notified: 0)
    end  
  end
```

Comment: Is `probable_associations` a core Rails feature?

Comment: @echan00 what is probable_associations?

Comment: Write `.flatten.to_sentence` instead of just `.to_sentence`. Btw this code will probably result in a lot of queries for single products. I suggest to rewrite that to and try to load all products in just one query.

Comment: It can be rewritten, but what is `probable_associations`?

Comment: Right, he needs `flatten` here, but the chain should be rewritten anyway.

Comment: @RichPeck probable_associations is a type of has_many asssociation between user and product

Comment: @SachinSingh probable_associations is a type of has_many asssociation between user and product

Comment: Thanks for reply! Thought as much :p -- My answer should help considerably

Comment: @tompave probable_associations is a type of has_many asssociation between user and product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an [ActiveRecord Association extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products do
        def not_notified
            select(:name).where(notified: 0)
        end
    end
end

#-> @user.products.not_notified
```

That's my contribution, but you could then use `@spickermann` & `@tompave`'s controbutions and use `.flatten.to_sentence`

Comment: I think he needs `flatten` to fix his snippet, but I would write it differently.

Comment: You're totally right - I just wanted to make an answer to show a different way to do what he's written. The big problem is `probable_associations` is a mystery

Comment: I think your answer would make a lot of sense if `notified` was an attribute of `Product`. Unfortunately the question doesn't make that bit very clear.

Comment: Yep but I think it's still a better to do it than he's got currently. I'll keep it up as it is for now, and if the OP wants me to refactor to accommodate his structure, I'll certainly do so. BTW if it was the case that `notified` was an attribute of `user`, I'd use a `scope` in the `User` model

Comment: I'm trying your answer now... seems like there is a problem. I'll update my question to show you what I have..

Comment: Thanks! We might need to go into a chat to get it right for you!

Comment: Sure. The problem is that you assume 'notified' is a field of product, but its actually a field of association, so either how it seems I need to traverse through both the product and association models. For this user query, I need to use the 'category' and 'notified' fields of association and also the 'name' field of product.

Comment: Associative data can be accessed with `proxy_association` - we *could* use that -- would you mind jumping into chat?

Comment: gchat? erik.chan[at]gmail

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `probable_associations` does would I rewrite the code to something like this:

```
product_ids = user.probable_associations.where(:notified => 0).map(&:product_id)
Product.where(:id => product_ids).map(&:name).to_sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `probable_associations` is just an ActiveRecord `has_many` association, and that you want to end up with a list of titles for `Product` records, you can use this:

```
ids = user.probable_associations
          .where(notified: 0)
          .pluck(:product_id)

result = Product.where(id: ids).pluck(:name).to_sentence
```

It's similar to @spikermann's answer, but `pluck(:column_name)` is faster than using a block and only extracts the required column from the DB.

---

Also, the reason your code produces that string is that, by the time you call `to_sentence`, you have an `Array` of sub-arrays. Each sub-array contains a single element: a product name.

That's because the second `collect` is sent to an `ActiveRecord::Relation` containing just one record.

You could have solved that problem with `flatten`, but the whole operation could just be refactored.